# After adding a UILabel to my view, how do I delete it?

Tags: iphone, uilabel

I have added a UILabel to my view programmatically like this:

```
myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 30.0f)];
myLabel.center = CGPointMake(160.0f, 120.0f);
myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
myLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size: 18.0];
myLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
myLabel.text = @"Hello";
[self.myView addSubview:myLabel];
```

To add a label to my view. What I can't seem to find out is once I'm done w/ the label (at a future point) how can I delete it from the view? `[myLabel release]` doesn't seem to work which I think makes sense because the view it's added to probably retained it's over reference. So what is the best practice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
[myLabel removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: Does take care of the cleanup or do I then need to do [myLabel release]?

Comment: addSubview increases the retain count, so for your example: yes. 
It's convention to do a [myLabel release] after the addSubview. In that case you don't have to release it afterward, and the removeFromSuperview will send the final release message.

HTH.

Comment: Would it also be correct to add it to the subview, and then release it after the removeFromSuperview?

Comment: Yes, that's what I wrote, though, a bit more dense. ;-)